# Jackson Json Wrap on field level

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there an annotation that I can use if I want to wrap a single field?

Say I have this class

```
class A {
   int field1;
   String field2;
}
```

I want to wrapped `field2` with another parent, so when it serialize it would be like this

```
{
   "field1": 77,
   "parent": {
       "field2": "Success"
   }
}
```

Currently I have two solution, which is using the Getter and return map, or creating a new class for field2, but I have a lot of field that requires this wrapping, so if there is a simpler solution like using an annotation, I want to utilize it.

Comment: maybe using JSON Jackson View https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the serialization you are looking for does not match the structure of your class A. How about putting a field on class A called "parent" which is an instance of "B"?

```
class A {
   int field1;
   B parent;
}

class B {
  String field2;
}
```

Comment: This is a solution, though I have around 20 fields that needs this changes, so creating 20 classes just to get this result seems excessive

Comment: Perhaps a little more clarification on the JSON input you are receiving? Are there twenty different names for each of the parents? Are the parent names irrelevant because each of the wrapped fields have distinct names? Maybe the best solution is for you to just parse the String into a JsonObject then iterate over the fields directly?